# How to query: agregate group by column A for each column B value

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

At this moment I have the following rows values:

[image: Reg table]

build this table with :

```
CREATE TABLE `registros` (
  `id_registro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_partida` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_juego` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_jugador` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `score` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fecha_creacion` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `registros` (`id_registro`, `id_partida`, `id_juego`, `id_jugador`, `score`, `fecha_creacion`) VALUES
(1, 2, 2, 1, 300, '2017-02-27 22:14:50'),
(2, 2, 2, 2, 350, '2017-02-27 22:14:50'),
(3, 2, 2, 3, 365, '2017-02-27 22:14:50'),
(4, 2, 2, 4, 110, '2017-02-27 22:14:50'),
(5, 2, 2, 5, 90, '2017-02-27 22:14:50'),
(6, 2, 2, 6, 840, '2017-02-27 22:15:11'),
(7, 2, 2, 7, 500, '2017-02-27 22:15:11'),
(8, 2, 2, 1, 20, '2017-02-27 22:15:45'),
(9, 2, 2, 1, 610, '2017-02-27 22:15:45'),
(10, 2, 2, 2, 415, '2017-02-27 22:16:07'),
(11, 2, 2, 4, 220, '2017-02-27 22:16:07'),
(13, 3, 1, 1, -600, '2017-02-27 22:17:47'),
(14, 3, 1, 1, -550, '2017-02-27 22:17:47'),
(15, 3, 1, 2, -480, '2017-02-27 22:17:47'),
(16, 3, 1, 2, -700, '2017-02-27 22:17:47'),
(17, 3, 1, 9, -490, '2017-02-27 22:18:18'),
(21, 3, 1, 2, -700, '2017-02-27 22:18:18');
```

And I need to get a group by `id_jugador` with his best score (a player who plays in a game some times with different scores) for each `id_partida` (game competition).

I have a "ranking" for each game. This is my sql code for it:

```
SELECT registros.id_partida, registros.id_jugador,MAX(registros.score) as best_score
FROM registros
WHERE registros.id_partida = 2
GROUP BY registros.id_jugador
ORDER BY best_score DESC;
```

And execution result:

[image: id_partida ranking]

But i want to know all ranks of all competitions and the position for the game. Not only using the where clause with a specific target `id_partida = 2`. Exactly as following:

[image]

Mysql database here: http://pastebin.com/8eYuYzgV

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by two columns:

```
SELECT registros.id_partida, registros.id_jugador,MAX(registros.score) as best_score
FROM registros
GROUP BY registros.id_jugador, registros.id_partida
ORDER BY best_score DESC;
```

If you want a rank in your query then the query will look slightly complex with MySQL:

```
select id_partida, id_jugador, best_score, rank
FROM (
select *,
case when @p=a.id_partida THEN @o:=@o+1 ELSE @o:=1 END as rank,
@p:=a.id_partida
from (
SELECT registros.id_partida, registros.id_jugador,MAX(registros.score) as best_score
FROM registros
GROUP BY registros.id_jugador, registros.id_partida
 ORDER BY registros.id_partida, best_score DESC
) a, (select @p:=0, @o:=1) s
) scores
```

Results:

```
| id_partida | id_jugador | best_score | rank |
|------------|------------|------------|------|
|          2 |          6 |        840 |    1 |
|          2 |          1 |        610 |    2 |
|          2 |          7 |        500 |    3 |
|          2 |          2 |        415 |    4 |
|          2 |          3 |        365 |    5 |
|          2 |          4 |        220 |    6 |
|          2 |          5 |         90 |    7 |
|          3 |          2 |       -480 |    1 |
|          3 |          9 |       -490 |    2 |
|          3 |          1 |       -550 |    3 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea9a61/10)

Comment: I feel stupid for not trying it before ... thank you a lot. Now i need to get the position column for all players